# Get attributes from relationship parent model

Tags: laravel

I'm loading some data for the user like this.

```
Method 1
$user->load(['subscription.payementTypes']);


Method 2
$user->load(['charity.payementTypes']);
```

Is there anyway I can figure out in the PaymentType model that it is called via subscription or charity?

I want to call an Accessor in PaymentType based on Subscription or Charity

```
// For Subscriptions
public function getPaymentDescriptionAttribute()
{
    // if Subscription

    // if Charity
}
```

The relationships are as follows.

```
//Class User
public function subscription()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Subscription::class);
}

public function charity()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Charity::class);
}

//Class Subscription
public function paymentTypes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(PaymentType::class);
}
```

Comment: in `Class Subscription` you should create a function  `payementTypes()` with `belongsToMany(PaymentType::class)`

Comment: there was a typo. I corrected it.  I want to get some attributes from Subscription model to perform a calculation in the Payment model

Answer (score 1):

I feel like in class Subscription, you should name it paymentTypes. I'd say it's a hasMany though?

```
public function paymentTypes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PaymentType::class);
}
```

and in the PaymentType you can do

```
public function subscription
{
return $this->belongsTo(Subscription::class);
}
```

Comment: there was a typo. I corrected it. the relationships are working correctly. I want to get some attributes from Subscription model to perform a calculation in the Payment model

Answer (score 1):

if it is not working you can do somthing like this

in `User.php`

```php
//Class User
public function subscriptionWithPaymentType()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Subscription::class)->with('paymentTypes');
}
```

then you can do this

```php
$user->load(['subscriptionWithPaymentType']);
```

Comment: The relationships are working correctly. I want to get some attributes from Subscription model to perform a calculation in the Payment model.

Comment: I'm currently map through the result collection of $user->load(['subscription.payementTypes']).
Then performs the calculation for each data. I thought this can be done easily using relationships.

Comment: you can use `accessor`  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: I changed the question.